# why is cv::warpPerspective outputting different values for the same inputs on Python vs. C++?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ransac, feature-matching

## Context:

I am trying to align an image using another image as reference, by using ORB + Ransac. I use python to prototype and c++ to deploy to android via dart:ffi. However, the result is good in python but not as good in c++, even tho, i **think** i wrote equivalent codes.

---

## Configs:

**C++**

- Opencv 4.8.0 (downloaded from opencv.org and compiled with mingw)
- Compiler: mingw
- CMAKE

**Python**

- 3.10.11
- opencv-python == 4.8.0.76 (the closest to 4.8.0 I've found);

---

## Inputs

The two input images are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nuq0BjBLdbYPFLIgA18u9D7kGbULb_WL?usp=sharing)

## Outputs

I was expecting the same output for the two codes, but that's not the case. Notice the black border on the bottom right in the cpp image.

[cpp_warped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIxtx.jpg),
[py_warped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDtcb.jpg)

---

## Code

### C++

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using std::string;
using cv::Mat;

Mat warp(Mat source, Mat reference){
    
    cv::Ptr<cv::ORB> detector = cv::ORB::create(5000);

    cv::Mat d1, d2;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> kp1, kp2;

    detector->detectAndCompute(source, cv::Mat(), kp1, d1);
    detector->detectAndCompute(reference, cv::Mat(), kp2, d2);

    cv::Ptr<cv::BFMatcher> matcher = cv::BFMatcher::create(cv::NORM_HAMMING, true);
    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
    matcher->match(d1, d2, matches);

    // sort by distances (ascending)
    std::sort(matches.begin(), matches.end(), [] (cv::DMatch a, cv::DMatch b){
        return a.distance < b.distance;
    });

    // take only top 90% matches
    int n_matches = floor(matches.size() * 0.9);

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> p1, p2;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_matches; i++){
        p1.push_back(kp1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        p2.push_back(kp2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    cv::Mat homography = cv::findHomography(p1, p2, cv::RANSAC);

    cv::Mat warped_mat;
    cv::warpPerspective(source, warped_mat, homography, cv::Size(reference.cols, reference.rows));

    cv::convertScaleAbs(warped_mat, warped_mat);

    return warped_mat;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Mat source = cv::imread("../source.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat reference = cv::imread("../reference.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // cv::imshow("source", source);
    // cv::waitKey(0);
    // cv::destroyAllWindows();

    Mat warped = warp(source, reference);


    cv::imwrite("cpp_warped.png", warped);
    return 0;
}
```

### Python

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def warp(source, reference):
    detector = cv.ORB.create(nfeatures=5000)

    kp1, d1 = detector.detectAndCompute(source, None)
    kp2, d2 = detector.detectAndCompute(reference, None)

    matcher = cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = matcher.match(d1, d2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key= lambda x: x.distance)    

    #take top 90%
    matches = matches[:int(len(matches) * 0.9)]
    n_matches = len(matches)

    p1 = np.zeros((n_matches, 2))
    p2 = np.zeros((n_matches, 2))

    for i in range(n_matches):
        p1[i, :] = kp1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt
        p2[i, :] = kp2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt

    homography, _ = cv.findHomography(p1, p2, cv.RANSAC)

    height, width = reference.shape
    warped = cv.warpPerspective(source, homography, (width, height))
    warped = cv.convertScaleAbs(warped)

    return warped

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = cv.imread("source.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    reference = cv.imread("reference.png", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    warped = warp(source, reference)
    cv.imwrite("py_warped.png", warped)
```

I double checked the default cv::ORB constructor parameters from python bindings and opencv c++, they are the same.
I also tried changing some parameters on the c++ code, but didn't achieve any result as good as in python.

## Edit:

Output of getbuildInformation:
[python](https://pastebin.com/y3ASMPYW),
[c++](https://pastebin.com/33rtdyS0)

Output of drawMatches:
[py_matches](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F3dQ-95liiNpeCctMflMTEfcwiXgWtB1/view?usp=sharing)
[cpp_matches](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IaL2UIQo8bzvjNanRWpUsdPT7IedwlPL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share the results of getBuildInformation in both environments? https://learnopencv.com/get-opencv-build-information-getbuildinformation/

Comment: and please use the drawMatches function to visualize and debug your keypoint detection and matching.

Comment: sure! i added these infos in the edit section.

Comment: hard to see, but it looks like the results of the matching are the same. So ORB detection/decsription and matching should be fine. Afair in findHomography you can get a mask of the inlier keypoints. Can you draw the inlier keypoints? They are the ones used to compute the homography and if there are wrong matches in the inliers, your homography will be corrupted.

Comment: there is one difference that's probably not relevant: `Point2f` is using single precision floats. By default `np.zeros()` gives you double floats. you could try making the python version use `np.zeros(..., dtype=np.float32)`

Comment: that code lacks Lowe's ratio test. that is usually vital for discarding ambiguous/weak matches. I know this here is using Hamming distance. browse `samples/python/find_obj.py` for details applicable to binary descriptors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sheet of paper is warped. It's not a flat plane in space. You put it half on top of your keyboard, half on the desk. It's warped.

RANSAC and all those will latch onto the largest cluster of agreeing matches. Those come from the textured area of the sheet, which is the multiple choice bubbles and the header.

The registration marks *should* be discarded as outliers by any algorithm that is given non-specific extracted features.

The nondeterministic nature of the solver algorithms means that you'd have to run all of this multiple times, then calculate statistics on the outcomes, and compare those. When you compare single results that are based on noise/randomness (that is different for each case!), you can't make any general statements.

---

Your code lacks Lowe's ratio test. It discards weak matches, those that aren't clear winners. Browse `samples/python/find_obj.py` in the OpenCV source tree (e.g. on GitHub) for details on how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the output of findHomography()?

It uses RANSAC which cannot guarantee to have the same output for each run (at least if you are not able to guarante the same seed for random number generation).

RANSAC is necessary if your data have outliers.
Even LMEDS is based on random sampling to be robust to outliers (LMEDS can properly works only if outliers are less than 50%) and therefore it cannot guarantee the same solution at each run.

If you have no outliers you can use the standard least squares method (use 0 instead of RANSAC) that uses all the input points. In this case the result should be the same for each run because least squares method follow a deterministic sequence of steps.

Comment: I am having many outliers. I tried switching to LMEDS and Least Squares Method but the results are very bad.

Comment: RHO gives me a good result, but, again, the python version output is much better.
Please notice that the result is not inconsistent across runs, but across codes.